# Elasticsearch monthly rolling indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've been using logstash to feed daily rolling indices in elasticsearch, something like this

```
   output {

        elasticsearch {

                ....
                index: myindex-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}
       }
   }
```

Now it turns out I need to use monthly rolling indices instead, after having a look at http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/outputs/elasticsearch.html#index

But I still feel confused, so is the answer as simple as to use `myindex-%{+YYYY.MM}` instead, and the index will be rolling at the end of each month?

Update:
Here are examples of the "same" event (that has same `_id` field) gets indexed on two different days

on day A, this is indexed

```
   {_id: 123, message: "old message}
```

on following day B, this is indexed

```
   {_id: 123, message: "updated message}
```

so if day A and day B belongs to two separate indices, I will have 2 events if my query looking back to all of these indices. To eliminate duplication, on indexing event B, I will do a additional check querying with `_id` and remove the previously existing event A then do index to B. if it's daily indices, as time going, I'm afraid my query on _id search will be more expensive, which monthly can improve. Last but not least, if the event found from my check exists in current index (today's to this month's), it won't remove the event but let elasticsearch to do the `update` based on `_id` (essentially it's a delete/create as well, just I don't need to do it in my code)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is that simple.

Comment: Thanks Jettro, I was able to test with changing system datetime in between indexing 2 events, and can see 2 indices being created.

Comment: I'm curious...  why the "need" to use monthly indexes?

Comment: @AlainCollins long strong short, there are events with same _id and other updated attributes feed in every day, if it's daily rolling indices, I will need a more frequent uniqueness check compare to use monthly indices - I still have to check but only query to indices that is not for current month

Comment: @JamesJiang Not sure if you mean it did not work for you. If that is what you mean can you post the message that is coming into log stash and the config. Could be that the timestamp is not as you expect or maybe another problem. I cannot post code in the comment so I post it in an answer.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie both monthly and daily worked, just I found monthly is more effective in my case. Updated the question with sample events

Answer (score 6):

What happens with the config you provide is that the timestamp of the event is taken. If you do no additional config the time the event was received by log stash is taken. However, it is often useful to take the timestamp that is within the event itself. Than this time stamp is used. Below some sample code that I often use.

```
filter {
  date {
      match => ["timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    protocal => "transport"
    host => "localhost:9300"
    cluster => "mycluster"
    index => "gridshore-logs-%{+YYYY.MM}"
  }
}
```

Comment: That make sense Jettro, we use Kibana as front where we normally set the timestamp field that we want to take, so it could be using logstash generated `@timestamp` to index but on dashboard we can use `ourtimestamp` field in the index configs - you can do the same to histograms and tables as well. still good to do as you suggested though.

Comment: There is a syntax error: `index => "gridshore-logs-%{+YYYY.MM}` => `index => "gridshore-logs-%{+YYYY.MM}"`